# Hazelcast client not able to connect to Hazelcast cluster in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs, hazelcast, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have the following situation:

I have a hazelcast cluster that's deployed on AWS ECS (FARGATE), using two availability zones, the discovery strategy is working correctly, and i can see all cluster members in each container.

I configured a load balancer (external) so i'll be able to access to the cluster REST API, so from the outside, i can access to http://my-cluster.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:5701/hazelcast/rest/cluster and check my cluster members

I have another app that contains a Hazelcast client, that i want to connect to the Hazelcast cluster. The thing is, when i use the load balancer address (http://my-cluster.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:5701) the app can not access to the cluster, but when i use a private ip of any member (ECS task) on my client properties, i can access it!

Here's the error i'm having :

```
Packet not sent to null ClientMessage{connection=null, length=115, operation=Client.Authentication, isRetryable=true, correlationId=1, messageType=100, isEvent=false, isfragmented=false}
```

And the connection is closed from the server side

i can provide properties or additional information if anyone can help!
Thank you